# Installing a HP Color LaserJet 1600 on MacOS 10.6.4

Tags: printing, macbook-pro, driver

I'm trying to install a [HP Color LaserJet 1600](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF10a/18972-18972-3328060-15077-3328070-1140734.html?jumpid=in_r2515_us/en/smb/psg/psc404redirect-ot-xx-xx-/chev/) on MacOS 10.6.4 with little luck. The printer works fine from my Windows machines. HP doesn't support the MacOS for this printer by default so I followed the instructions from this forum post: http://macosx.com/forums/hardware-peripherals/302806-hp-lazer-1600-printer-driver-mac.html.

The post offers several solutions but I followed the instructions from whiskynwhisky and downloaded a Unix driver from here: http://www.mediafire.com/?nocydet5wml. The instructions included with the download were straightforward and I now have the driver installed and the printer in System Preferences. Unfortunately while jobs queue and dequeue they do not actually print. Are there other options to get this printer to work on my MacBook Air? Do I need to do something differently with the driver I already have installed?

Comment: There are a small number of HP LaserJet models that simply do not support Mac OS X. My wife owns one, a different, monochrome model. Good luck, as I have never found a solution to this problem myself.

Comment: See http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c03411613 for a list of HP printers not supported on OS X.

Comment: @Patrix Please make your comment an answer so I can delete my answer and mark yours as the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HP has published a list of [printers not supported on OS X Mountain Lion](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c03411613) on their web site:

> **Products not supported**
>
> The following products are not supported in Mac OS X including the Mountain Lion operating system
>
> ...
>
> - HP Color LaserJet 1500 and 1600 Printer series

Answer (score -1):

There is a [app](http://www.netputing.com/handyprint/) that claims to be able to print to legacy printers.

I am unable to confirm that since I do not have such a printer.

> handyPrint™ v3.1 is a 64bit (core 2 duo or better) Mac OSX application
>   that allow you to print from your iPods, iPads and iPhones on legacy
>   printers that do not support the AirPrint protocol.

Comment: Disclaimer:, I do not have your printer to verify my answer first. So it is up to you if you want to try it.

Comment: Good idea about using the non-US website (Canon drivers have the same problem), but this seems to only be a firmware update utility and not a driver.